# Select in Spring MVC by enum

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, enums

What is way to select enum from database? I have:

```
<select name="country">
  <c:forEach items="${countries}" var="value">
    <option value="${value}">${value}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

I have in class and table 'User' field string/varchar 'country'

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the [option](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-form.tld.option) and [options](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-form.tld.options) tags from the spring forms tld.

If I understand it correctly, you will have to add `YourEnum.values()` to the model, say as "enumValues" (according to comments below, this is not necessary).

```
<form:select path="foo">
     <form:option value="-" label="--Please Select"/>
     <form:options items="${enumValues}" />
</form:select>
```

**Reference:**

- [16.2.4.10 The option tag](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-optiontag)

Comment: Funny thing - I had the same question, found this post, cut/pasted the code you provided, changed the name of the path, and it worked.  I never put "enumValues" into my model and the only place Spring could be getting the enum values from is by reflecting on the "set" argument for the path. Turns out, all you need is the "<frm:options />" entry - no "items" attribute, and Spring grabs the enum names for you automatically.  Best thing is that this behaviour isn't documented ANYWHERE in the spring docs.  I'm using 3.0.6, by and by.

Comment: @ogradyjd: This is an interessting feature. But it is documented, not in the docs but in the spring-form-tld for attribute `items` of tag `options`: "... This attribute is required unless the containing select's property for data binding is an Enum, in which case the enum's values are used."