# spring webflow 2 binding: how to populate <select> with enum values

Tags: jsp, select, binding, enums, spring-webflow-2

I'm working with spring webflow 2 and I'm facing the issue of presenting a form for user registration. The user has to insert name, surname... and his/her nationality. This is the model class:

```
    @Component
    @Entity
    @Table (name = "personal_data")
    public class PersonalData implements Serializable {

@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column (name = "id")
private Integer id;

@Column (name = "name", nullable=false)
private String name;

@Column (name = "familyName", nullable=false)
private String familyName;

@Column (name = "nationality")
@Enumerated (EnumType.STRING)
private Nationality nationality;

    //getters and setters
    }
```

Where Nationality is:

```
public enum Nationality {
    Afghan, Albanian , Algerian , American , Andorran , Angolan , Antiguans , Argentinean , Armenian ...
}
```

I can bind everything with spring webflow and the form is showing properly. But I can't fill up the  tag

The jsp is:

```
<tr>
            <td><spring:message code="label.familyName"/>:</td>
            <td><form:input path="personalData.familyName" /> <form:errors path="personalData.familyName"/> </td>
        </tr>

            <td><spring:message code="label.name"/>:</td>
            <td><form:input path="personalData.name" /> <form:errors path="personalData.name"/> </td>
        </tr>

            <td><spring:message code="label.nationality"/>:</td>
            <td><form:select path="personalData.nationality"/> <form:errors path="personalData.nationality"/>

                </td>
        </tr>
```

And the spring webflow is defined as:

```
    <var name="profile" class="com.tclouds.tpaas.models.user.UserProfile"/>

    <view-state id="registerProfile" view="profile/create1" model="profile">
        <transition on="submitRegistration" to="confirmData"/>
    </view-state>
```

Can you please tell  me how can I populate the

many thanks

Comment: [Have a look at comments as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014280/select-in-spring-mvc-by-enum][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014280/select-in-spring-mvc-by-enum

Answer (score 4):

"items" attribute in  `<form:options />` tag shows the following documentation:

> The Collection, Map or array of objects used to generate the inner
>   'option' tags. This attribute is required unless the containing
>   select's property for data binding is an Enum, in which case the
>   enum's values are used.

So you just have to add the `<form:options />` tag without any attribute inside the select. That will make the select get filled with the enumeration items as texts and values. You also can add a default "choose" option. For example:

```
<form:select path="personalData.nationality">
    <option value="">Choose a nationality</option>
    <form:options />
</form:select>
```

That code will produce the following html output:

```
<select name="personalData.nationality">
    <option value="">Choose a nationality</option>
    <option value="Afghan">Afghan</option>
    <option value="Albanian">Albanian</option>
    <option value="Algerian">Algerian</option>
    <option value="American">American</option>
    <option value="Andorran">Andorran</option>
    <option value="Angolan">Angolan</option>
    <option value="Antiguans">Antiguans</option>
    <option value="Argentinean">Argentinean</option>
    <option value="Armenian">Armenian</option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps.