# Why do I get an error using this enum as option items in JSTL

Tags: java, spring, jstl, el

The enum is defined as:

```
public enum Country {
    US("United States"),
    CA("Canada"),
    AUS("Australia");

    private String fullName;

    private Country(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
}
```

The Model is:

```
public class Workspace implements Serializable {
    // ...
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private Address address;
    //...
}

public class Address implements Serializable {
    // ...
    private Country country;
    //...
}
```

I have a view object as such:

```
public class WorkspaceVO implements Serializable {
    //..
    private Workspace workspace;
    //...
}
```

And finally in my jsp I'm trying to do:

```
<form:select id="country"  path="workspace.address.country">
  <form:options items="${workspace.address.country}" itemLabel="fullName"/>
</form:select>
```

I have this exact situation duplicated in other spots in my code and its working fine.  I don't see any difference, however, I'm getting an error when I visit the jsp...

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Type [com.mycompany.web.Country] is not valid for option items

Any ideas why?

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014280/select-in-spring-mvc-by-enum

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple mistake: `form:options items` is the value for the list that contains all the options!

So in the controller, add a variable to your modelmap

```
modelMap.add("aviableCountries", Country.values);
```

and then use it in the jsp:

```
<form:select id="country"  path="workspace.address.country">
   <form:options items="${aviableCountries}" itemLabel="fullName"/>
</form:select>
```

---

**Edit**: an other solution is the remove the `items` attribute completely

```
<form:select id="country"  path="workspace.address.country">
   <form:options itemLabel="fullName"/>
</form:select>
```

then you do not need to add the enum values in the controller. This works because of an not well known feature of `spring-form:options`-Tag. In the tld for the `items` value, you can read:

> ... This attribute *(items)* is required unless the containing select's property for data binding is an Enum, in which case the enum's values are used.

In the code of `org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.OptionsTag` you will find this if-statement:

```
if (items != null) {
    itemsObject = ...;
} else {
     Class<?> selectTagBoundType = ((SelectTag) findAncestorWithClass(this, SelectTag.class))
            .getBindStatus().getValueType();
      if (selectTagBoundType != null && selectTagBoundType.isEnum()) {
            itemsObject = selectTagBoundType.getEnumConstants();
      }
}
```

Comment: the first part of the answer where you suggest adding the enum to the modelmap isn't what I was looking for at all...It shouldn't need to be added that way.  I've done extremely similar other set up using this code on other pages just like I'm doing here and it works fine.

Comment: Your edit however does give me a working alternative.  Still very strange that it doesn't work on this page when I have basically the same code on three other pages and they all work as expected.

Comment: @kasdega: then there must be some other effects that you do not described in the question. Believe me I have had a close look at the code of springs options tag yesterday and today too.

Comment: @kasdega: if it work exactly in this way in two other places, then propably because the value you pass though `items` is `null` an therfor the options tag behave like you have not set it at all (my edit) and therefore it uses the enum's values automatically.