# Enum-based Radio Buttons in Freemarker backed by Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, freemarker

Is it possible to output a list of radio buttons in Freemarker using the Sping MVC JSP tag-Freemarker macros, based on the Enum type of a bound property? I gather [this is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014280/select-in-spring-mvc-by-enum) using the `<form:select>` tag in JSP, but can it be done with radio buttons and in Freemarker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this.  The easiest thing to do is put an array of your enum values into your model:

```
model.put("myEnum", MyEnum.values());
```

In your FTL, you just iterate over those:

```
<#-- handy macro for this -->
<#macro enumSelect selectName enumValues>
    <select name="${selectName}">
        <#list enumValues as enum>
        <option value="${enum}">${enum.description}</option>
        </#list>
    </select>
</#macro>

<#-- calling the macro -->
<@enumSelect "myEnumSelectName" myEnum/>
```

This code assumes that `MyEnum` has a method called `getDescription`.  You can do whatever you like to support the option text.  You can also add to this macro so support a "selected" option, etc.

Comment: perfect other than it should be   `<option value="${enum}">${enum.description}</option>`

Comment: Thanks @BillComer, I fixed it.